# driving a medium power darlington transistor with the output of a 555 timer

Tags: pwm, 555, darlington, trigger, matching

Question: What is the limitation on the output of the 555 timer with respect to the requirements of the input of the BDW42G? Can the 555  provide enough current at 5 volts to trigger (sufficiently) the input (base) of the BDW42G?

I am using a 555 timer to generate the pwm signal and would like to drive a power Darlington transistor like the BDW42G.

The Hfe of the BDW42G is 250 for 10amp Collector Emitter

Darlington output requirements: 90volts DC at 10Amps (max)

Comment: What does the 555 data sheet tell you about output drive capabilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a circuit like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNXGgZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Ratings of components do not tell us how to design the circuit.

Here, if the 555 can provide a HIGH output into 100 ohms in series with 1.5 or 2.0 volts of the Darlington two-diode base input, then this circuit will work.

However, the TI 555 datasheet, (if powered with +5v) promises only 2.75 volts output
with **NO** current promised. At +12 volts, you can pull 0.2 amps.